# Tinymce fontsizeselect is not using "theme_advanced_font_sizes" or "font_size_style_values" values

Tags: javascript, plugins, tinymce, editor

I'm initializing tinymce with:

```
tinymce.init({
    theme_advanced_font_sizes: "10px,11px,12px,13px,14px,15px,16px,17px,18px,20px,22px",
    font_size_style_values: "10px,11px,12px,13px,14px,15px,16px,17px,18px,20px,22px",
});
```

but the font size shown are still the defaults of `"8pt, 10pt, "`, etc.

How do I make tinymce use my font sizes?

**Using: tinymce 4.0.6**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TinyMCE changed the value to:

`fontsize_formats`

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:fontsize_formats

There is no documentation to let users know of this change.